# SFML How to draw heap of multiple textures at specific time

Tags: c++, sfml

Hello I'm making a game using SFML, but I ran into some problems.

I want to complete this function:
if a human character collide with items, one garbage draw on screen. (5 textures)
So multiple textures of garbages stack up from the bottom of the window.

I tried to use vector and Sprite array, but my codes can't add garbages. It just draw one garbage, and then change another textures.
What should I do to keep garbages drawn until `window` closes?

I should add many Sprites to solve this problem, but I have no ideas... I've done everything I can.

My code is here:

```
// out of main loop
Texture GarbagesTexture[5];
GarbagesTexture[0] = garbageTex1;
GarbagesTexture[1] = garbageTex2;
GarbagesTexture[2] = garbageTex3;
GarbagesTexture[3] = garbageTex4;
GarbagesTexture[4] = garbageTex5;
int SelectedGarbage = 0;

vector<Sprite> Garbages;
Position GarbagesPosition;
GarbagesPosition.x = 890.f;
GarbagesPosition.y = 590.f;

// main loop
//collision
for (size_t i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
{
        if (humanArr[index].getGlobalBounds().intersects(item[i].getGlobalBounds()))
        {
          ...
          ...
          CollisionTime++;
          SelectedGarbage++;
          if (SelectedGarbage > 5) SelectedGarbage = 0;
          GarbagesPosition.x = GarbagesPosition.x - 10.f;
          GarbagesPosition.y = GarbagesPosition.y - 5.f;

          Sprite GarbageInputSprite;
          Garbages.push_back(GarbageInputSprite);
          Garbages[i].setTexture(GarbagesTexture[SelectedGarbage];
          Garbages[i].setPosition(GarbagesPosition.x, GarbagesPosition.y);
          }
   }

 //draw
 window.clear();
 ...
 ...
 for (int i = 0; i < CollisionTime; i++)
      window.draw(Garbages[i]);   
 window.display();
```

I am a poor beginner in SFML, but I'll try to do my best.
I would really appreciate it if you could help me solve this problem.

Comment: Look at `Garbages[i]` when you set a texture, now look what is `i` -- it's an index of item, not an index of last garbage you added. It's hard to understand what you want exactly, but I assume you would want to first `setTexture` and `setPosition` of `GarbageInputSprite` and only then you `push_back` it into vector. That way you update the most recent garbage

Comment: Thx for your answer! but `Garbages[i]` is by design. There are also 5 textures of items. I want that when a human collides with `item[0]`, `Garbages[0]` has to be drawn on screen. If the human collided 5 times, there should be 5 garbages on screen. I completed changing garbages after collision, but I'm having trouble keeping the previous textures of `Garbages` from being erased. This is what I want exactly.

Comment: I'm sorry I am not good at English. thank you for reading it !

Comment: Maybe I'm too sleepy to understand, but you add a garbage in `Garbages` on every hit, so there are more sprites than items in `Garbages`. However with `Garbages[i]` you change only the first garbage for this item, while I assume other garbages for same item are transparent, since they have no texture

Comment: May I ask what ideas you have-about how to add textures to other garbages-?